Does every permutation composition puzzle (like the Rubik's Cube) have a practical solution algorithm?
Let $R$ be a set of permutations that generates a group $G\subset S_n$. The "puzzle problem" corresponding to $R$ is: Given an element $g\in G$ (written in a standard permutation notation), find a word in $R$ that represents $g$.
One brute-force algorithm to solve any puzzle problem involves just generating all the elements of $G$ by multiplying out $R$-words (in increasing order of length, say) and looking for $g$. If $G$ is large, this takes a long time (or bundles a lot of pre-computed data in the algorithm description), on the order of $|G|$.
The $m\times m\times m$ Rubik's Cube is a permutation puzzle (with $R\subset S_{6m^2}$, $|R|=3m$) that has a more practical solution procedure. The standard algorithm used by human solvers amounts to a program whose "cost" (sum of description length and worst-case runtime) is bounded by a polynomial in $|R|$ as $m$ grows, even though $|G|$ grows much faster.
Can something similar be said about the family of all permutation puzzles? That is, is there a polynomial $f$ such that every permutation puzzle $R$ has a solution algorithm whose cost is less than $f(|R|)$?
(To clarify, the quantifier order here is "$\exists f\forall n\forall R\exists A$". Each algorithm $A$ has a finite cost since it solves a specific finite puzzle $R$, so we're not exactly doing asymptotic runtime analysis in the standard sense.)

Is $n$ fixed? Is $f$ dependent on $n$? And how? I mean without further requirements the answer is trivially yes since the set of puzzles is finite (when $n$ is fixed). Please clarify.

Ah and if $f$ is not allowed to depend on $n$, the answer is trivially no. But still not sure what you exactly ask here.

@MartinBrandenburg Sorry if the phrasing isn't clear - I want a "universal" $f$ that depends only on its argument $|R|$, as $R$ ranges over all permutation puzzles (and $n$ ranges over all $\Bbb N$). Why is the answer trivially no?

Certainly not in a cost only dependant on the size of $R$ -- every $S_n$ can be generated by two elements.
What one can prove (Keywords: Schreier-Sims algorithm, Stabilizer Chain) is that there is a polynomial of degree 7 in $n$, that is degree dependent, bounding the runtime of building a data structure that describes $G$ and allows for factorization of elements of $G$ as words in the given generators. These word expressions can be found in the same time bound, if you allow the algorithm to define intermediate values, for example defining $c=ab$ first and then expressing $(ab)^{100}$ as $c^{100}$.
This being a general algorithm, the words it produces typically are far away (probably exponentially far away) from the optimum.

Thanks! I guess it was hasty of me to expect all of the $n$-dependence to "factor through $|R|$". I'll read about Schreier-Sims - I'm wondering how it would work on puzzles where $|R|$ (and hence the description of $G$) is larger than $f(n)$.

There is an implicit assumption that $|R|\le n$. So one would have to increase $n$ in that case.

I see, Wikipedia says it runs in $O(n^2 \log^3 |G| + tn \log |G|)$ time where $t$ is the number of generators.
